# How to create a new array containing data from an other array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

How do I create a new array from this array

```
String[] data = {"day: monday, color: green", "day: sunday, color: blue", "day: thursday, color: red"};
```

that looks like this:

```
String[] data = {"green", "blue", "red"};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with what AlexR says about figuring it out for yourself.  Here's another way to envision the for-loop and parse operation using the [substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method.  Again, be sure to preallocate a String array to hold the results before hand, ie:

`String[] result = new String[data.length];`

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    // gets the substring starting on the 5th character
    String color = data[i].substring(5);

    // adds String to result
    result[i] = color;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, create new array of the same size:

```
String[] colors = new String[data.length];
```

Then iterate over the source array parse each value and put it to the result. There are a lot of ways to parse your strings. It depends on how strong the parsing should be. Here is the simplest way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    String[] d = data[i].split(" ");
    colors[i] = d[d.length - 1];
}
```

No more comments. Try to understand the code yourself. It is really trivial.